# Standalone application in Grails

Tags: grails

I need do a application in Grails 3. I need execute a service from the shell.
for example

```
java -jar app.jar PruebaService
```

Answer (score 0):

I learned it also here on SO couple of weeks ago from cfrick :)

grails package  - will do it very groovy

I just tested it again on 3.RC2